# How can I separate a stroke from the raster image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke

I've added a stroke to a rasterised image (`Edit -> Stroke`). Now, how do I select the stroke so I can copy it into a new layer and delete the current layer, leaving me with just the outline of the image?

I'm using Photoshop CC on a Mac.

Comment: Menu layer ==> Laure style. That would create 2 layers

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ways to do this:

If you're going to use `Edit -> Stroke` then you must've selected your image first. After you select it create a new layer BEFORE doing the stroke. Then you can delete or do anything else you want to the image below it.

A better way however is to use `Layer -> Layer Style -> Stroke`. This will give you much more control over the stroke and afterwords you can go onto your layer panel and instead of lowering Opacity to 0%, lower the Fill to 0%. The stroke will remain at the 100% opacity while the fill within it will be reduced to 0.

If you're using shape layers initially then you can use the settings specifically for the shape vectors, but it doesn't sound like that's the case.

Comment: Add to that, right-click on the stroke effect in the Layers panel and choose `Create Layer`, then select the original object and delete the selection area from the "stroke" layer. (Photoshop doesn't actually create a stroke on the new layer, but a solid that's [stroke width] larger than the original object, so you have to do that additional step.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Layer > Duplicate Layer
2. Hide original layer
3. Layer > Layer Style > Blending Options
4. For Stroke, set Size "1px" and Position "Inside"
5. For Blending Options (Advanced Blending), set Fill Opacity "0%"